# How Make the Graph Style Data Source in PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder-pfc

I am new in powerbuilder,

I have a table with 3 columns ; `Quantity,Price,Year` and i want to create a graphical data in power builder with data window properties. i selected the graph style from data style and returns the table in to it. Now how can i get the graphical representation of table corresponding data. Can you give me the procedure step by step ,I am using PB 10.0

Answer (score 0):

from here explain what you ask would be like making a help manual, I would recommend that you execute the "Code Samples" in the installation of PowerBuilder sure you find what you need, also in the following url you have many other examples . I hope it helps you.

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SYBPB/SAP+PowerBuilder